# Does this image confirm that I have definitely installed angular CLI globally or not?

Tags: angularjs

[image: Installation of Angular CLI globally]

Does it surely mean that angular CLI globally is installed on my ubuntu?

Comment: I am unable to identify it confidently that whether i have installed Angular CLI globally correctly.

Comment: Please attach to question cli output as a text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it install globally into your Ubuntu system.